# index.html page is not working in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and am trying to create login page. It was working fine before but now I have used ngStorage.min.js for my profile file to store the response, then my index.html is not working now.

I am getting below error in Mozilla Firefox and am getting nothing in my Chrome.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/index.html [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 3ms]
GET https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 255ms]
GET https://cdn.rawgit.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example/master/app-content/app.css [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 267ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/css/login.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 5ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/css/register.css [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 4ms]
GET http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 323ms]
GET https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1021ms]
GET https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1294ms]
GET https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-cookies.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1294ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/js/ngStorage.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 317ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/js/ngStorage.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 318ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/app.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 318ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/app-services/authentication.service.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 319ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/app-services/user.service.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 319ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/app-services/flash.service.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 320ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/controller/home.controller.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 320ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/controller/login.controller.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 325ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/controller/userdata.controller.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 325ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/controller/register.controller.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 325ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/controller/resetpassword.controller.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 325ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:49905/app-services/user.service.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
```

My **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cornflourblue/angular-registration-login-example/master/app-content/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/register.css">
</head>

<body>

 <div class="main-wrapper" >     
        <div ng-class="{ 'alert': flash, 'alert-success': flash.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': flash.type === 'error' }" ng-if="flash" ng-bind="flash.message"></div>
        <div ng-view></div>
      </div>


  <div class="credits text-center">

  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ngStorage.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="app-services/authentication.service.js"></script>

  <!-- real time API storage-->
  <script src = "app-services/user.service.js"></script>
  <script src="app-services/flash.service.js"></script>


  <!-- Fake user service for demo that uses local storage -->
  <script src="app-services/user.service.js"></script>

  <script src="controller/home.controller.js"></script>
  <script src="controller/login.controller.js"></script>
  <script src="controller/userdata.controller.js"></script>
  <script src="controller/register.controller.js"></script>
  <script src="controller/resetpassword.controller.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you don't paste the error that you get on firefox. the "GET" lign are not error but browser loading your files

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you've included the ngStorage script twice:

```
<script src="js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ngStorage.js"></script>
```

Try removing one of those lines and do a hard refresh (Shift + click Reload) and see if that helps.